# Multiple y-axis in horizontalBar chart js

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, chart.js

I'm trying to plot multiple y-axis in chartjs using a `horizontalBar` chart.

Here's what the final graph should look like:

[image]

Here's my chart config:

```
{
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'A',
      yAxisID: 'A',
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }, {
      label: 'B',
      yAxisID: 'B',
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'A',
        position: 'left'
      }, {
        id: 'B',
        position: 'right'
      }]
    }
  }
```

The first dataset (the blue one) shows up correctly *and* with the correct y-axis values (ie. `a`, `b`, `c`, etc.)

But the second dataset does not appear at all. Also, the y-axis for the second dataset (right side), shows `50`, `40`, `30`, etc. instead of `a`, `b`, `c`...

**PS:** It is mandatory to show both the y-axes. This is because I have to plot the positive values (blue ones) against the y-axis on the right side, and the negative values (red ones) against the y-axis on the left side.

Here's the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vjt2r1mL/356/)

Comment: @ℊααnd Thanks, but that's not what I exactly want, because there is still single y-axis on the left. I have to show tick labels on the right side (using the second y-axis), for all the positive (blue) values

Comment: @ℊααnd I've added an image of what I finally expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your second 'data' object's 'label' and 'yAxisID' values from 'B' to 'A'.  Also, you can delete your second 'yAxes' object at the bottom.

So it would look like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('chart');
new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'A',
      yAxisID: 'A',
      data: [100, 90, 80, 70, 60],
      backgroundColor: 'blue'
    }, {
      label: 'A',
      yAxisID: 'A',
      data: [-100, -90, -80, -70, -60],
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        id: 'A',
        position: 'left'
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vjt2r1mL/362/

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I exactly want, because there is still single y-axis on the left. I have to show tick labels on the right side (using the second y-axis), for all the positive (blue) values